# Default Google Apps CNAME Records?

Tags: google-apps, cname

I recently got a domain registered through Namecheap. I successfully set up mail.mydomain.com to redirect to my organization's Google Apps Gmail by setting up mail to point to ghs.google.com. My question is how does Google know that I want it to go to Gmail and not Calendar? Granted, it's obvious in this case, but what if I were to point a "foobar" subdomain to ghs.google.com? What would it do? I'm a web developer, but I hardly ever do anything with server configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google server @ ghs.google.com looks at the incoming request. if it is say - cal.yourdomain.com, it serves calendar and if it is mymail.yourdomain.com, it serves gmail.

What happens is

- User (cal.yourdomain.com) -> resolve to ghs.google.com
- Send request for cal.yourdomain.com to ghs.google.com
- ghs.google.com sees that the incoming request is for cal.yourdomain.com
- is there an entry for cal.google.com? What service is it? Serve the appropriate page.

How does google know to do this?
You specify this on the dashboard at - https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourdomain.com/DomainSettings#ServiceSettings/service=calendar&subtab=0

and choose "Change URL"

You will need to do this for every service you use. Make sure you create appropriate CNAME records with your DNS service provider.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I knew how to deal with the Namecheap side of things, just not the Google side of things.

Comment: Small update to this, according to: `https://support.google.com/a/answer/53340?hl=en` the host to resolve to is `ghs.googlehosted.com`

Answer (score 0):

Some of the [G Suite Core Services](https://gsuite.google.com/terms/user_features.html) are supported as CNAMEs to ghs.googlehosted.com: calendar, docs, drive, groups, hangouts, mail, plus, sites, slides, vault

and some are not: contacts, forms, jamboard, keep, meet, tasks